# Angular 13 production build timing out in Azure DevOps after one hour

Tags: angular, azure-devops

We recently upgraded from Angular 9 to Angular 13.3.12 and our production build in Azure DevOps went from 20-25 min to timing out after 1 hour. I really don't know where to begin researching what the issue could be. Any help appreciated!

Here is the full build log:
https://gist.github.com/chriskooken/d2ca1dbf1519cd467a9786e08a4ddce7

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/azuremediaplayer.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you identify which process/task in the build phase is taking so long?

Comment: The first thing I would probably do is time the build locally with `--stats-json` and try to look at what the problem could be there.

I would also double check that the node and npm versions in your pipeline are updated to something more recent. I know I had to move to npm 8 from 6 when doing angular upgrades around those version numbers.

Comment: My co-worker just added a link to the build log, in the original description

Comment: Post your tsconfig(s) please.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I've added the tsconfigs. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think the issue is in tsConfig. It seemed weird that in your log it mentioned all of these "entryPoints" having deep imports.  Yet none of those should be entry points, unless, this is a library and you're building all those as separate packages?

Comment: You seem to be using `dart-sass` and the build seems to get stuck while compiling sass. There is a [known issue](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1913) about the performance of certain versions of the library: as advised in the final comments, try upgrading the version of the library to at least `1.61.0`. I hope it helps in the resolution of the issue.

Comment: I recommend upgrading `ng2-material-dropdown` and `devextreme-angular` libraries and trying again (since issues appear to be with these two libraries). Also, if you have any other libraries in your `package.json` file that must be upgraded because you switched to `Angular 13` make sure you upgrade them.

Comment: @jccampanero dart-sass isnt in our package.josn How do we upgrade that?

Comment: @miselking ng2-material-dropdown isnt in our package.json. How should we upgrade that?

Comment: @ChrisKooken You are right, it is a dependency that comes from `ngx-chips` so make sure to upgrade that one (to `version 3`) and hopefully it will resolve the `ng2-material-dropdown` issue. As for `dart-sass` it could be that you are using an old `ngx-bootstrap` or some other library that has deprecated `sass` inside it as a dependency. Make sure to update all your libraries (in `package.json` file) to versions compatible with Angular 13.

Comment: @ChrisKooken probably it is included by a third party dependency. I am not aware of your exact use case, but you can include `dart-sass` as a dependency by itself if necessary, probably as a dev dependency in your `package.json`: it will be picked by npm while installing.